# how to declare a list of object nullable asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

Good Morning , 
I'm a beginner in asp .net
Acually I  prepare the database using the first code approach 
And my question is:  How to declare a list of objects that can be null ?

[image]

Comment: like `List<object> val = null`?

Comment: `List<Nullable<int>> ids` ?  It's not really clear what you're asking.  Have you tried something and is it failing in a specific way?

Comment: A good tip for the future - stay around when you've posted your question. It's in the first fifteen minutes that you're likely to get the most questions for clarification that you need to respond to. If you're not here to respond, people will make assumptions, and you run the risk of having your question downvoted and put on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your diagram, I'm guessing what you meant is that your Employer object may have 0 or more BonDeCommande object. As such `List<BonDeCommande>` is what you want (which may have an empty list -- rather than null)

```
public class Employer {
    public string code {get; set;}
    public string mdp {get; set;}
    ...
    public List<BonDeCommande> bonDeCommandes {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes that's exactelly what I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int?> aList = new List<int?>();
```

The question mark means that the value can be null

Comment: OP already knows how to make a list of nullable ints, as they clearly state in their question. They want to know how to make a list of nullable objects  (or a list that is nullable, possibly) which might confuse the rest of us, because we already know that objects are implicitly nullable, because they're objects.

Comment: Yes , I mean how to make a list of nullable objects of '' Bon De Commande ' in the class ' Employee '   :( and sorry because my question was not clear

Answer (score 0):

List it self can be null, so the object you do not have to specify that somehow else. After last line of example code, list "val" will contain object o =null.

```
List<object> val = null;
List<object> val = new List<object>();
object o = new object();
o = null;
val.Add(o);
```